# GDB tool on zephyr

Tags: gdb, zephyr-rtos

I am working a project on zephyr OS and I want to debug my code. Does anyone know how to use GDB debugging tool with west flash or build? Generally to combine it with zephyr west in order to start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
west debug
```

is probably what you are looking for. If it was executed successfully the gdb command prompt is active.

Answer (score 0):

For `arm64`, please run: `west build -t debugserver`

and, in another terminal: `gdb-multiarch zephyr.elf`

`zephyr.elf` is the result of the compilation and it is located in `./build/zephyr/` folder.